# Edit file side by side for translation in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, translation

I have to translate a lot of files in multiple languages.  I would like to use notepad++ with "move to the other view" then "Synchronize Vertical Scrolling".

The document is written so that lines are synchronized between documents.  Translation of the line #5 appears on the line #5.

I would like to highlight the line which have the same number in the other view that the one under my cursor on this view.  Is it possible and how?

Comment: I have done beter in vim : syncbind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In menu **Plugins**, use **Plugin Manager** to download [**Compare** plugin](https://github.com/jsleroy/compare-plugin). This plugin does exactly what you need: After restart of Notepad++, in menu **Plugins**, check sub-menu **Compare**.